# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'superfish'

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I People

I have a  Magento ver. 1.8.0.0 installed and works fine with the superfish menu dropdown.
How ever every time I install a news system , I get all sorts of errors, can any one help?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' bootstrap.js:156
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js:156
(anonymous function) bootstrap.js:158
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'superfish' superfish.js:124
(anonymous function) superfish.js:124
n jquery-1.7.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery-1.7.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery-1.7.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C jquery-1.7.min.js:2
```

It seems to have an issue with this line in superfish.js

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.sf-menu').superfish()
})
```

Object # has no method 'superfish'

Any Ideas?
Thanks Carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have multiple instances of jquery in your page, for example if you load again jquery after superfish the superfish methods will no longer exist in the current jquery instance.

To solve this problem you need to edit your extensions/template configuration and load jquery only one time at the beggining before any jquery plugin.

Or you can use an extension that handles the jquery library like EasyjQuery: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-jquery.html